# Create procedure MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So I've been trying to do this simple procedure but for some reason when I run the code in a call statement it brings up an error saying "[`ERROR in query 1`] Result consisted of more than one row". I've ran each of the statements in the procedure individually and they work perfectly, returning one row. So obviously I must have a syntax error somewhere. If someone could shed light on this that would be great.

```
    DELIMITER ;;

    CREATE PROCEDURE userInfo(in uID int, out fullname varchar(50), out occupation varchar(50), out NumOrders int(11), out DVDCount int(11), out VehicleCount int(11))
    BEGIN
    SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) INTO fullname FROM users WHERE userid = uID;

    SELECT occupation into occupation FROM occupation JOIN users ON users.occupationid = occupation.occupationid WHERE userid = uID;

    SELECT count(*) INTO NumOrders FROM orderitem
    JOIN orders ON orders.orderid = orderitem.orderid
    JOIN users ON orders.userid = users.userid
    WHERE users.userid = uID;

    SELECT count(*) INTO DVDCount FROM userDVD WHERE userid = uID;

    SELECT count(*) INTO VehicleCount FROM userVehicle WHERE userid = uID;
    END;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE userInfo(in uID int, out fullname varchar(50), out occupation varchar(50), out NumOrders int(11), out DVDCount int(11), out VehicleCount int(11))
BEGIN
SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) INTO fullname FROM users WHERE userid = uID LIMIT 1;

SELECT COALESCE(occupation, 'no occupation') into occupation FROM occupation JOIN users ON users.occupationid = occupation.occupationid WHERE userid = uID LIMIT 1;

SELECT count(*) INTO NumOrders FROM orderitem
JOIN orders ON orders.orderid = orderitem.orderid
JOIN users ON orders.userid = users.userid
WHERE users.userid = uID;

SELECT count(*) INTO DVDCount FROM userDVD WHERE userid = uID;

SELECT count(*) INTO VehicleCount FROM userVehicle WHERE userid = uID;
END;;
```

Comment: Hey Teliaz. I tried running this and it comes up with the following error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as fulname,

(SELECT occupation into occupation FROM occupation JOIN users ON us' at line 3"

Comment: try changing table occupation to occupations or filed name occupation to occupation_name 
also corrected the query

Comment: Okay, this works well and it does what I need it to do. So I guess this is solved. The only problem I seem to be facing right now is the fact that most of the information it is returning is incorrect. Not sure why though because if I run these queries on their own they run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `out occupation varchar(50)`  which is a string vaiable but you are selecting multiple rows. You should consider using a temporary table for that matter (OR) just return the resultset like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE userInfo(
            in uID int, 
            out fullname varchar(50), 
            out NumOrders int(11), 
            out DVDCount int(11), out VehicleCount int(11))
BEGIN
SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) INTO fullname 
FROM users WHERE userid = uID;

SELECT occupation FROM occupation 
JOIN users ON users.occupationid = occupation.occupationid 
WHERE userid = uID; // this query

SELECT count(*) INTO NumOrders FROM orderitem
JOIN orders ON orders.orderid = orderitem.orderid
JOIN users ON orders.userid = users.userid
WHERE users.userid = uID;

SELECT count(*) INTO DVDCount FROM userDVD WHERE userid = uID;

SELECT count(*) INTO VehicleCount FROM userVehicle WHERE userid = uID;
END;
```

Comment: I sort of understand what you're doing but I also don't. In your code you still have the occupation select but you took it out of the userInfo(). Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes and that's what I said. just the select query result set. don't try storing it into variable which was the issue.

Comment: I attempted to run your code and it came up with "[ERROR in query 1] Undeclared variable: occupation"

Comment: @the_lonely_doge, shouldn't be as I have already removed the reference.

Comment: Do you really have a column named `occupation`? if not then change it accordingly.

Comment: never mind I must have ran a different statement. But, removing occupation is not what I need here. I need to be able to see the users occupation when I call the procedure. Although it is still coming up with the error "[ERROR in query 1] Result consisted of more than one row" when I run the call statement

Comment: And yes I have a column called "occupation" in a table.